# Get view from Fragment using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I used [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) and have to fragments.

In each fragments, I used `AsyncTask` to get data from server.

Below is my fragment class that gets html from server and displays listview.

```
public class MainFragmentSubList extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_list, container, false);
    ListView mainList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_list);

    ArrayList<String> infoList;

    // this is AsyncTask class and i made an interface.
    new GetHtml(new OnRequestFinish(){
        @Override 
        void onFinish(){
            // Below are about ui
            ArrayList<String> titleList = (ArrayList<String>) User.subName.clone();
            int size = infoList.size();
            MainListAdapter adapter = new MainListAdapter(titleList, infoList, size + 1);
            mainList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }  
    }).execute();

    return view;
}
```

Since AsyncTask does things in background, `return view;` didn't work as I expected.

Here is my main activity that has fragments.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    tabs.setShouldExpand(true);
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
}
}
```

How can I return View from fragment using AsyncTask?

Comment: Why want to return ` View` from AsyncTask?

Comment: I want to return `view` in fragment class. I just used AsyncTask because I have to get files from server.

Comment: Is there any error?Or what is the result you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Sir why want to return view in fragment class?

Comment: PagerSlidingTabStrip requires fragments to return view. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and setup your view in `onCreateView`. Init and set your adapter too, with an empty list. For convenience you make the adapter and your list member variables.

Make sure that `onFinish` is invoked by AsyncTask's `onPostExecute`, so that it runs on the correct thread. When it is called, you update your list and then call the adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged()` method.